# binding event with jquery in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Description:**

I have many dropdowns on my page that all call a "update price" function. This is so that when  user selects an option, the price changes accordingly. There are many of these dropdowns and they all have similar names `sizes-1`, `sizes-2`, etc

**Problem**

I am finding myself copy/pasting extremely similar event binding code because I can't figure out how to bind it through some sort of loop.

Example:

- Static

  ```
  $( '.sizes-1' ).on('change', function() {
          sizes[0] = $(this).val();
          p.update_pricing( slider_values, price_fields, sizes, ); 
  });
  ```
- Attempt at a loop ( not working )

  ```
  for( index = 0; index < number of divs; index++ ) {        
      $( '.sizes-' + index ).on('change', function() {
          sizes[ index ] = $(this).val();
          p.update_pricing( slider_values, price_fields, sizes, );                
      });
  }
  ```

There are going to be many `.sizes` divs on this page and I don't want to copy/paste that static code 30+ times. I was wondering if anyone ran into a similar problem and knows a solution?

Thank you very much.

Edit: ( copy/pasted code )

```
for( index = 0; index < num_divs; index++ ) { 
    ( function( context_index ) {     
          $( '.sizes-' + context_index ).on( 'change', function() {
            sizes[ context_index ] = $(this).val();
            p.update_pricing( slider_values, price_fields, sizes );                
         });
    } ( index ) ); 
}
```

Comment: ID being like `size-1`, `size-2` is understandable. But why would you have 30+ dropdowns with different class as such? A single class as `sizes` would really have solved your problem.

Comment: Why not to give them the same class?

Comment: Also in the 2nd version, the index inside the `.change` will not be the correct value as the value of `i` will be equal to `number of divs` at the time of executing the handler function.

Comment: how would that solve my problem, O_o, as I need the values from each `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a CSS class to all of your select HTML elements and then, use jQuery CSS selector to retrieve all of them

```
<select class="selectSpecial" id="sizes-1">...</select>
<select class="selectSpecial" id="sizes-2">...</select>
etc
```

And you retrieve all your select with

```
$(".selectSpecial").on('change', function(changeEvent) {

    var index = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('size-', '')) - 1;
    sizes[index] = $(this).val();
    p.update_pricing( slider_values, price_fields, sizes);

});
```

Comment: how would I uniquely get the value of the select and place them in an array? this wouldn't work.

Comment: You could place "size-1", "size-2" etc as id of your select element instead of class, and then retrieve the index of your array with this id : $(this).attr('id').replace('size-',''). The closure solution is good but you are creating a lot of anonymous function.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I could retrieve the values? I am confused as to where I would put `$(this).attr('id').replace('size-', '')`

Comment: Just an FYI. I figured out what you were saying :)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you tie up your function **within a closure** so that the context is saved for that particular index..

```
for( index = 0; index < number of divs; index++ ) { 
     (function(contextIndex) {     
         $( '.sizes-' + contextIndex ).on('change', function() {
             sizes[ contextIndex] = $(this).val();
             p.update_pricing( slider_values, price_fields, sizes, );                
         });
    }(index)); 
 }
```

Comment: This is not working for whatever reason. The binding are not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a common class name (or target `select` directly if this works in your situation:

```
$( '.sizes' ).on('change', function() {  // <---- Note 'sizes'
    sizes[0] = $(this).val();
    p.update_pricing( slider_values, price_fields, sizes, ); 
});
```

HTML

```
<select class="sizes sizes-1">
    <-- options here -->
</select>
```

This will apply your function to all select boxes with the `sizes` class.